# Convert nvarchar to numeric in MSSQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a nvarchar column with a list of entries such as (including NULLs)-

```
-1.00000
0.000000
0.010000
0.100000
0.500000
00000000
1.000000
1.500000
10.00000
10.50000
100.0000
1000.000
1001.000
1006.000
NULL
NULL
```

I want to convert this to a numeric field so that I can use this field to do some calculations. However, I get the following error message-

> Error converting data type nvarchar to float.

Can someone please help?

Comment: Edit your question and include as simple a query you can that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your data would appear to have values are not valid numeric values.  Use `try_convert()`:

```
select try_convert(numeric(38, 12), col)
```

This will return `NULL` if there is a failure in the conversion.

You can find the values that fail the conversion by doing:

```
select col
from t
where try_convert(numeric(38, 12), col) is null and col is not null;
```

You need to use `try_convert()` wherever you reference the column as a numeric.  Converting in the `select` only applies to the `select`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but that doesn't work. Gives the same error message

Comment: @HM8689 of that, I am doubtful. `TRY_CONVERT` won't generate that error; as if the conversion fails *`NULL`* is returned. perhaps you could edit your post with your (new) query?

Comment: @HM8689, you'll need to post your actual query. Depending on the particulars of you query and execution plan, SQL Server might attempt to convert the value before `TRY_CONVERT` is evaluated.

Comment: Thank you- this is working fine! There was another conversion as well which had to be coded as try_convert to make it work.

Comment: Though `try_convert` works from SQL Server (starting with 2012) .i'm getting an error `Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 2
'TRY_CONVERT' is not a recognized built-in function name.` when i tried with an example : 'SELECT TRY_CONVERT(INT, 'A100.000') AS ValueInt`

Comment: Whereas `TRY_PARSE` and `TRY_CAST` functions are working fine :(

Comment: @Mahesh.K . . . That doesn't quite make sense, but you can use `try_cast()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Just to demonstrate Gordon's method in case OP needs:

```
create table #test(val nvarchar(100));

insert into #test values
('-1.00000'),
('0.000000'),
('0.010000'),
('0.100000'),
('0.500000'),
('00000000'),
('1.000000'),
('1.500000'),
('10.00000'),
('10.50000'),
('100.0000'),
('1000.000'),
('1001.000'),
('1006.000'),
(NULL),
(NULL)

select val, TRY_CONVERT(numeric(38,12),val) as converted_val from #test
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `try_convert(numeric(38,5), [ColumnName])`

This will return NULL when it cannot convert the string. If it can, it will be able to convert it to a numeric number

Answer (score 1):

You can try the convert function in SQLServer:

```
select Convert(float, "column_name") from TABLE
```

Empty fields are returned as 0.