# Fetching SAP table data throws Error 8114

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, sap-data-dictionary

I'm trying to update SQL data from SAP data (same happens with insert). I'm always getting runtime error

> SQL error 8114
>
> The reason for the exception is:
>
> Database error text: "Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric."

All fields of 'gs_sap_table2' are type **CHAR100**. I've tried many things like converting some fields of my structure from CHAR 100 to decimal 18,5 and fill all the 'NOT NULL' SQL fields with values but problem remains.

I'm posting you my ABAP code and a picture of the SQL database fields:

```
      EXEC SQL.
        CONNECT TO :gv_connection
      ENDEXEC.

      EXEC SQL.
        UPDATE STOCKKEEPINGUNITS
           SET ProductId           = :GS_SAP_TABLE2-PRODUCTID,
               CreatedOn           = :GS_SAP_TABLE2-CREATEDON,
               UpdatedOn           = :GS_SAP_TABLE2-UPDATEDON,
               UPC                 = :GS_SAP_TABLE2-UPC,
               AvailabilityType    = :GS_SAP_TABLE2-AVAILABILITYTYPE,
               Stock               = :GS_SAP_TABLE2-STOCK,
               Currency            = :GS_SAP_TABLE2-CURRENCY,
               TaxClass            = :GS_SAP_TABLE2-TAXCLASS,
               RetailCurrentPrice  = :GS_SAP_TABLE2-RETAILCURRPRICE,
               Weight              = :GS_SAP_TABLE2-WEIGHT,
               MeasurementUnitId   = :GS_SAP_TABLE2-MEASUREMENTUID,
               NameL1              = :GS_SAP_TABLE2-NAMEL1,
               NameL2              = :GS_SAP_TABLE2-NAMEL2,
               ShippingCost        = :GS_SAP_TABLE2-SHIPPINGCOST
        WHERE SKUId = :GS_SAP_TABLE2-SKUID
      ENDEXEC.

      EXEC SQL.
        COMMIT
      ENDEXEC.

      EXEC SQL.
        DISCONNECT :gv_connection
      ENDEXEC.
```

[image]

Comment: you should always put MSSQL version, in data conversion tasks it matters

Answer (score 3):

The error tells you that there is an `nvarchar` value and it is being attempted to be implicitly converted into a numeric type. So, the error happens either in the `SET` or the `WHERE` clause. Since in the `WHERE` clause from the two operands one is the field, `SKUId`, which is a `varchar` and not an `nvarchar` nor a numeric type, it is clear that the error happens somewhere in the `SET` clause.

In the `SET` clause you assign values to fields. Conversion from `nvarchar` to numeric happens in these assignments if and only if the right-hand-side (i.e. **the value**) is `nvarchar` and the left-hand-side (i.e. the **field**) is numeric.

So, in order to fix your issue, you will need to

- create a list for yourself containing all numeric fields in the `SET` clause that receive some value
- make sure that the value (right-hand-side) of the assignment operation for each field is [converted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48806702/convert-nvarchar-to-numeric-in-mssql-server) into a numeric value of the exact type your field expects